# Move information from on-premise databases's view to Azure Sql database

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory

Since we can copy data from on-premise SqlServer database to Azure storage using ADF by providing tableName in dataset

```
"type": "SqlServerTable",
    "linkedServiceName": "&#60;Linked service name&#62;",
    "typeProperties": {
        "tableName": "&#60;table name&#62;",
    }
```

Is it possible to copy data from view instead of table and if yes then how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible, You can use Copy Activity in Azure Data Factory.

As you aware you first need to create Data Management gateway to connect to On-Prem server.
Create Linked Services, Data sources etc.,
While creating pipeline create COPY activity and provide the query from view

```
SELECT * from dbo.viewName
```

Configure the target data sources in the pipeline and configure slicing. This will take care for copying data from On-Prem to SQL Azure

Answer (score 0):

Yes. SQL treats views just like tables.
Follow this [article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/data-factory-sqlserver-connector/#invoking-stored-procedure-for-sql-sink) to get it set up from beginning to the end.